# javascript inheritance confusion

Tags: javascript, inheritance

this is some code

```
var Animal = function (name,color,sound){
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.sound = sound;
}

Animal.prototype.doSomething = function (){
                              alert(this.sound);
}

var cate = new Animal('cate','black','meow');

cat.doSomething(); \\alerts 'meow' 

now i create another constructor function 

var Person = function (name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

below i initialized a Person.prototype with Animal.prototype

```
Person.prototype = Animal.prototype;
```

so now as we know objects are assigned as a reference `Person.prototype = Animal.prototype` 
will assign `Animal.prototype` to `Person.prototype` so if we add to `Person.prototype` a method like

```
Person.prototype.doSomethingElse = function (){
                                   alert("some text to test");
}
```

does Animal.Prototype also gets the `doSomethingElse` method of `Person.prototype` .

```
cate.doSomethingElse();
```

Comment: Not sure. Give it a shot and find out! http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/d4g3a/

Comment: Yes, it does. Is that the question?

Comment: yes, so is it good thing ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clear things up, if you do:

```
function Animal(){}
function Person(){}

Person.prototype = Animal.prototype;
```

Then `Animal` and `Person` share the same `prototype` object and all instances of `Animal` and `Person` constructed after the assignment have the same `[[Prototype]]`.

If you do:

```
Person.prototype = new Animal();
```

that will make `Person.prototype` an instance of `Animal`, so while instances of `Person` will share all methods of `Animal.prototype`, instances of `Animal` will not share any **own** properties of `Person.prototype`.

e.g. if you add a method to `Person.prototype`, it's not inherited by instances of `Animal`:

```
Person.prototype.foo = function(){};
var p = new Person();
var a = new Animal();

typeof p.foo; // function
typeof a.foo; // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, both prototype references are the exact same object. When you say

```
Person.prototype = Animal.prototype;
```

then

```
Person.prototype === Animal.prototype; // true
```

So any method you add to `Person.prototype` will also be in `Animal.prototype` (actually, not "also"; there is only one object serving as the prototype for both constructors).

To avoid that you can use a function like [this](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html):

```
function object(o) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
}
Person.prototype = object(Animal.prototype);
```

In modern browsers, you can just use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) instead:

```
Person.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
```

Comment: when i alert(Animal.doSomethingElse); its undefined ?

Comment: Because you added it to Person.prototype, so Animals don't have it, only Persons.

Comment: so i'm assuming in javascript arguments are passed by value to methods by default, that's the only your explanation would make sense.

Comment: Yes, noting that values are either primitives (number, string) or references to objects (as in this case).

Comment: @raziqijr I'm not sure what you want. The way you're doing (shared prototype) is not recommended, because Person does not have its own prototype. If you add Person.prototype.talk, you'll make cats talk. The code I showed is a way to *avoid* that. Still, anything you add to Animal.prototype will still be available on Person instances (but not vice versa).

Comment: @RobG Person.prototype = Animal.prototype the reference is assigned here so they both point to same prototype the doSomethingElse method should be available what do u say?

Comment: @bfavaretto i am just asking if i add to Person.prototype any thing will it be also available on Animal.prototype ?

Comment: alert(Animal.doSomethingElse); undefined ?

Comment: Animal is not Animal.prototype. doSomethingElse will be available on Animal and Person *instances* like cat.

Comment: @bfavaretto sorry animal is not Animal.prototype ? could pls explain a bit more

Comment: @bfavaretto thank u very much , i forgot the prototype in Animal.prototype.doSomethingElse. thank u very much